# Celery - [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed

Tags: ssl, heroku, ssl-certificate, celery, django-celery

I have the following celery configuration for my Django project hosted on heroku/git -

```
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'App.settings')


app = Celery('App')

app.conf.timezone = 'Europe/London'

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.conf.update(BROKER_URL=str(os.getenv('REDIS_URL')),
                CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND=str(os.getenv('REDIS_URL')),
                broker_use_ssl = {
                        'ssl_cert_reqs': ssl.CERT_REQUIRED
                    },
                    redis_backend_use_ssl = {
                        'ssl_cert_reqs': ssl.CERT_REQUIRED
                    }
                    )
```

However when I run celery I get the following log error message.

```
ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to rediss://****************//: Error 1 connecting to *************. [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed
```

I can fix this by setting ssl_cert_reqs': ssl.CERT_NONE however then I receive the following warning -

```
Setting ssl_cert_reqs=CERT_NONE when connecting to redis means that celery will not valdate the identity of the redis broker when connecting. This leaves you vulnerable to man in the middle attacks.
```

Does anyone know how I can solve this to use SSL with Celery to protect my project going forward?

Comment: Normally for troubleshooting cert issues, I start with trying to connect using openssl and the internal CA store to validate that it has the certificates it needs. I start with `openssl s_client -connect <host>:<port>` and if that returns 0 (ok) then it's on to figure out why the libs in the framework don't have the CA certificates. If it doesn't return 0, then the cert needs to be added to the CA.

Comment: You can't add ssl certs to your project on heroku?

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried updating your SSL certificate? For Unix, running something like this code in your IDE should do it (found on GitHub).

```
import os
import os.path
import ssl
import stat
import subprocess
import sys

STAT_0o775 = ( stat.S_IRUSR | stat.S_IWUSR | stat.S_IXUSR
             | stat.S_IRGRP | stat.S_IWGRP | stat.S_IXGRP
             | stat.S_IROTH |                stat.S_IXOTH )


def main():
    openssl_dir, openssl_cafile = os.path.split(
        ssl.get_default_verify_paths().openssl_cafile)

    print(" -- pip install --upgrade certifi")
    subprocess.check_call([sys.executable,
        "-E", "-s", "-m", "pip", "install", "--upgrade", "certifi"])

    import certifi

    # change working directory to the default SSL directory
    os.chdir(openssl_dir)
    relpath_to_certifi_cafile = os.path.relpath(certifi.where())
    print(" -- removing any existing file or link")
    try:
        os.remove(openssl_cafile)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        pass
    print(" -- creating symlink to certifi certificate bundle")
    os.symlink(relpath_to_certifi_cafile, openssl_cafile)
    print(" -- setting permissions")
    os.chmod(openssl_cafile, STAT_0o775)
    print(" -- update complete")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```